# not recognize mcrypt module on Yosemite php

Tags: php, osx-yosemite, mcrypt

When i activate a mcrypt function inside a PHP file from the command line everything works fine but when I try to the same but from the localhost I'm getting this error:

Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_iv_size() 
I have a feeling that for some reason that it is using two different PHP's.

I've checked and the localhost and in the command line the php.ini is the same.

How can i know which PHP it is using?

Comment: `phpinfo()` will tell you exactly what .ini files are being loaded.

Comment: Do you have two versions of PHP installed?

Comment: @MarcB I know. I've checked and I've updated the ini with the extention=mcrypt.so and the dir and still nothing.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I have no idea. How can i check?